# Cloudflare free version asked to update name server again after 1 month for one of the domains

Tags: cdn, cloudflare, nameserver

I have moved one of my website to use Free cloudflare CDN so i changed my Name servers on my registrar to point to cloudflare Name server

When setting up i was asked to change name server to

- christian.ns.cloudflare.com
- cruz.ns.cloudflare.com

which i did an everything was working fine as my domain was active...

Today i logged in to cloudflare to check as normal and i noticed for this domain cloudflare is not active so i checked and noticed its asking to update Name Server on my registrar which i had done in past so upon checking further i noticed this time its asking me to use different name server for c xxxDomain.com which was changed 1 month back

[image]

I am not sure why its asking me to update name server again to below as i had done it in past.

- ivy.ns.cloudflare.com
- yichun.ns.cloudflare.com

Is it normal with cloudflare for free account or there could be any other reason for this

Comment: When a website in your CloudFlare account is inactive for a period of time and then you make it active again, CloudFlare will assign whatever nameservers it has available at that time. The real question to ask yourself is _why_ it became inactive, if you don't already know. On CloudFlare's side, you can check the [audit log](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002833612-Understanding-Cloudflare-Audit-Logs) for your account to see if there were any changes. You can also contact your registrar's support to ask them if they can lookup the history of nameservers for your domain.

Comment: If the nameservers changed with your registrar due to either a transfer, DNS update, expiration, or something else...then your website in CloudFlare will become inactive. You should have received an email from them in that case, so review your emails, and check that your email address is correct in your CloudFlare account.

Comment: DNS changed on on Cloudflare side when i checked our registrar it was still pointing to NS which cloudflare had provide and i am still not sure why domain became inactive on cloudflare and i was asked to us different NS on my registrar which is quite strange as i have other 76 domains and non of them has such issue in past.. its just one domain which became inactive. not it fine as i update our NS record to new NS as provided bycloudflare.. But question is still why did this happen?

Comment: also data for previous month is all gone.. after i updated NS... so if this happens with someone who has been using cloudflare for quite long they also tend to lose all data such as analytics specially

Comment: "But question is still why did this happen?" Did you ask Cloudflare? "on cloudflare and i was asked to us different NS on my registrar which is quite strange" if your DNS provider, no matter which, decides to change nameservers for your domain (for a ton of possible reasons, technical or not), then it has no way to change them through your registrar (except in specific circumstances... or when your DNS provider is also your registrar!), so you have to do it. Normally it should warn you though in some way, because old nameservers may stop answering DNS requests for your domain name...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek, i have contacted them also have not heard from them so far. My Registrar is Network Solution where i had changed NS to point to cloudflare NS as mentioned in my question and then my account domain became deactive without know any reason of email from cloudflare. and in this Network Solution had no roll to play as cloudflare has deactiavted domain as asking to change NS to new name server... these are the question i am trying to get answer for, i posted it here thinking someone else may have encountered similar issue... chasing CF for this issue. free account may time to get ans

Comment: @Learning Did you review the audit log for your CloudFlare account as commented about above? This really isn't something we can answer for you because we do not know the actions that took place with your CloudFlare account or your registrar(s). You'll need to follow up with CloudFlare if it's not apparent to you.

Comment: Dan, I did check Audit log and it doesn't point to anything which mentions of change in NS all i could see Red Add.. May be it needs an expert eye.. anyways thanks